# VSTS Web test recorder(12.0) buttons are not enabled in IE11

Tags: visual-studio-2013, performance-testing, load-testing, webtest

Am facing a problem with Web-Test Recorder window i.e I have ensure that the web test recorder plugin is enabled under manage add on.

Am using VSTS 2013 Ultimate and IE11 .

When I click on the recorder button , the IE window pop up with the Web test recorder but the recorder buttons like record,pause, stop,comments are not enabled.

I have uninstalled the VSTS and installed once again and tried. Tried with deleting the Register keys for IE as well.

Can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks,

Prabhakar.Y

Comment: @All, I tried to run VSTS as Admin then the problem got solved .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to run VSTS as Admin then the problem got solved